# Javascript - graph traversal - return shortest path

Tags: javascript, graph-theory, graph-algorithm, graph-traversal

I want to traverse a graph. I have two structures:

```
var Node = function(name) {  
    this.edge_list = [];
    this.name = name;
};
```

and

```
var Graph = function() {  
    this.node_list = [];
};
```

An edge is added to a Node like so:

```
Node.prototype.addEdge = function(end, distance) {  
    this.edge_list.push({end, distance});
};
```

A graph might look like this:

```
start:
[ Object { end: '1', distance: 13 },
  Object { end: '2', distance: 14 } ]
1:
[ Object { end: 'start', distance: 13 },
  Object { end: '3', distance: 2 } ]
2:
[ Object { end: 'start', distance: 14 },
  Object { end: '3', distance: 1 } ]
3:
[ Object { end: '1', distance: 2 },
  Object { end: '2', distance: 1 },
  Object { end: 'end', distance: 10 } ]
end:
[ Object { end: '3', distance: 10 } ]
```

What I'm looking to do is create a function that will return the shortest distance/path from a `source` to a `target`.

I currently have a test up https://repl.it/C6Fh

Comment: Try taking a look at the depth-first search algorithm first. Then look at Dijkstra's algorithm (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm)

Answer (score 0):

If the distances are positive, then dijkstra is the way to go. However, a very simple algorithm is:

- mark each node having an infinite distance, with the source node having a distance of 0.
- perform a breadth-first traversal on the graph starting from the source:

  - update a node's distance if the current edge leads to a smaller distance
  - add that node to the end of the queue

Following is my quick solution that stores the distances and the previous nodes on your Node class.

You will find the minimum distance on the node itself, like `dstNode.distance`.
For the path, just trace back from `dstNode` and follow the `prev` links.

```
function shortest_path(g, src, dst) {
    var get_node = function(n) {
        for (var i = 0; i < g.node_list.length; i++) {
            if (g.node_list[i].name == n) {
                return g.node_list[i];
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    var srcNode = get_node(src);
    var dstNode = get_node(dst);
    for(var i = 0; i < g.node_list.length; i++) {
        // think of as infinity (currently assumed to be unreachable)
        g.node_list[i].distance = 2147483647;
        g.node_list[i].prev = null;
    }
    srcNode.distance = 0; // src node is of distance zero from itself

    q = [srcNode]; // we will breadth-first traverse the graph
    while (q.length > 0) {
        var cur = q[0];
        q.shift();
        for (var i = 0; i < cur.edge_list.length; i++) {
            n = get_node(cur.edge_list[i].end);
            // here we are looping through neighbors of cur
            // to see if a smaller distance exists
            if (n.distance > cur.distance + cur.edge_list[i].distance) {
                n.distance = cur.distance + cur.edge_list[i].distance;
                n.prev = cur;
                q.push(n);
            }
        }
    }
}
```